# Creating a custom multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been stumped on this for awhile and was wondering if there was a way to turn this data into a custom multidimensional array.

I run a query on my table and it spits out an array like this

```
SELECT id_cms_category, name FROM cms_category_lang ORDER BY id_cms_category ASC
```

The resulted array looks like this.

```
array
0=>
  array
  'id_cms_category'=> 1
  'name'=>'Home'
1=>
  array
  'id_cms_category'=> 2
  'name'=>'Test'
```

So then I run my query on my cms table

```
SELECT cl.id_cms, c.id_cms_category, cl.meta_title 
FROM cms_lang cl
LEFT JOIN cms c ON (c.id_cms = cl.id_cms) 
LEFT JOIN cms_link ci ON (ci.id_cms = cl.id_cms)
ORDER BY c.id_cms_category, cl.meta_title ASC
```

and I get an array like this

```
array
0 => 
array
  'id_cms' => string '4' (length=1)
  'id_cms_category' => string '1' (length=1)
  'meta_title' => string 'About us' (length=8)
 1 => 
array
  'id_cms' => string '6' (length=1)
  'id_cms_category' => string '1' (length=1)
  'meta_title' => string 'Contact Us' (length=10)
 2 => 
array
  'id_cms' => string '1' (length=1)
  'id_cms_category' => string '1' (length=1)
  'meta_title' => string 'Delivery' (length=8)
 3 => 
array
  'id_cms' => string '2' (length=1)
  'id_cms_category' => string '1' (length=1)
  'meta_title' => string 'Legal Notice' (length=12)
 4 => 
array
  'id_cms' => string '5' (length=1)
  'id_cms_category' => string '1' (length=1)
  'meta_title' => string 'Secure payment' (length=14)
 5 => 
array
  'id_cms' => string '3' (length=1)
  'id_cms_category' => string '1' (length=1)
  'meta_title' => string 'Terms and conditions of use' (length=27)
 6 => 
array
  'id_cms' => string '10' (length=2)
  'id_cms_category' => string '2' (length=1)
  'meta_title' => string 'FAQ - UltraTech IBC Spill Pallet Plus' (length=37)
 7 => 
array
  'id_cms' => string '9' (length=1)
  'id_cms_category' => string '2' (length=1)
  'meta_title' => string 'FAQ - UltraTech P2 Plus 2-Drum Hard Top Spill Pallet' (length=52)
 8 => 
array
  'id_cms' => string '7' (length=1)
  'id_cms_category' => string '2' (length=1)
  'meta_title' => string 'XR-5, Urethane & Copolymer 2000' (length=31)
```

I am wanting to try and take all this data and somehow create a multidimensional array like so;

```
array
0 => 'Home'
        array
         id_cms => meta_title
1 => 'Test'
        array
         id_cms => meta_title
```

that way I should be able to run something like this

```
foreach($title as $key => $value)
{
    <li>$value</li>
    foreach($value as $id_cms => $page)
    {
        <li><a href="$id_cms">$page</a></li>
    }
}
```

to get the output on the page to look something like this

```
Home
  home 1
  home 2
  home 3
Test
  test 1
  test 2
  test 3
```

Comment: Which fetch method are you using to retrieve your results?

Comment: @FabienWarniez This is using the eCommerce platform Prestashop, they use PDO and within their DB class their object is called executeS which executes the sql query and makes all the data from the result available in a multidimensional array.

Comment: I see. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do two queries for this.

I would alter your second query so you've got both the category and page name in the same result set. It should look something like:

```
SELECT cl.id_cms, c.id_cms_category, catlang.name, cl.meta_title 
FROM cms_lang cl
LEFT JOIN cms c 
     ON (c.id_cms = cl.id_cms) 
LEFT JOIN cms_link ci 
     ON (ci.id_cms = cl.id_cms)
LEFT JOIN cms_category_lang catlang 
     ON (catlang.id_cms_category = cl.id_cms_category)
ORDER BY c.id_cms_category, catlang.name, cl.meta_title ASC;
```

Then you could create a loop that simply checked the category in each iteration. If it finds a new one, end the previous block and start a new one:

```
$currentCategory = '';
$output = '';
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($currentCategory != $row['name']) {
        $output .= '</li><li>' . $row['name'];
    }
    $currentCategory = $row['name'];
    $output .= '<li><a href="' . $row['id_cms'] . '">' . $row['meta_title'] . '</li>';     
}

// Trim off our unnecessary </li>
$output = substr($output, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your CMS returns a numerically indexed array (and that's what it sounds like from your post), you can re-index the array using whatever key you want.

```
$array = array(0 => array('id_cms' => 4, 'id_cms_category' => 1, 'meta_title' => 'About us'));
$newArray = array();
foreach ( $array as $v ) {
    $newArray[$v['meta_title']] = $v;   
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Arrays are vital in PHP programming, so you'd be doing yourself a favor to learn them before going any further.

Comment: Where is $array coming from?

Comment: It is a PHP variable that is defined as an example.

Comment: It has static content in it?

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a new empty array: `$newArray = array();`
2. Go through your result with a foreach, then as you go, check if the category of the current item already exists in your new array: `if (isset($newArray[$row['id_cms_category']))`
3. If it doesn't, create it and initialize it with a new array containing the item as a first element: `$newArray[$row['id_cms_category'] = array($row);`
4. If it already existed (i.e. you already went through an item belonging to this category), then add it: `$newArray[$row['id_cms_category'] []= $row;`

That's it!

Comment: That isn't going to work.  Why would you use 'id_cms_category' as the key when it is not unique to each record?  How do you know the code uses $row?

Comment: It's not unique to each record, exactly, what OP wants to do is group his records by the category. That's why I use id_cms_category as the key, and the value is an array containing the records that belong to that category.

Comment: And why $row? Because it represents one record / row. When I say 'go through your results', it's easy to understand that you have to do a foreach ($result as $row) and you can replace $result and $row by whatever you want... it's just a var name.

Comment: Let's try this.  Please explain what you think '$newArray[$row['id_cms_category'] =[] $row' does.

Comment: $row['id_cms_category'] is the category that OP wants to group by, ie. 'Home', 'Test'. That line adds $row as a new object of the array containing all the entries of the category 'Home' for example.

Comment: It isn't valid PHP.  It won't run.

Comment: Oh really? That is definitely valid PHP. Are you thrown off by []=?

Comment: Oops, it's []= and not =[]

Comment: "$newArray[$row['id_cms_category'] []= $row;"?  You're almost there.  Try again.